# Problem giving color to a logo

Tags: tikz-pgf, logos

I'm writing a manual for a class, and I never liked add images as files in my tex, so I'm drawning the logo with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,1.}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0.,0.,1.}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.75,0.75,0.75}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip(-4.42,-1.90) rectangle (8.03,4.69);
\draw [color=red,fill=red,fill opacity=1.0] (-0.67,1.06) circle (2.41cm);
\draw [color=white,fill=white,fill opacity=1.0] (-0.66,1.71) circle (1.92cm);
\draw [shift={(-0.05,2.21)},color=red]  plot[domain=2.01:4.03,variable=\t]({1.*1.40*cos(\t r)+0.*1.40*sin(\t r)},{0.*1.40*cos(\t r)+1.*1.40*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(-1.60,0.27)},color=red]  plot[domain=-0.48:0.92,variable=\t]({1.*1.08*cos(\t r)+0.*1.08*sin(\t r)},{0.*1.08*cos(\t r)+1.*1.08*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(-1.26,1.06)},color=red]  plot[domain=-1.12:0.68,variable=\t]({1.*1.43*cos(\t r)+0.*1.43*sin(\t r)},{0.*1.43*cos(\t r)+1.*1.43*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(0.42,3.0)},color=red] plot[domain=2.72:4.22,variable=\t]({1.*1.18*cos(\t r)+0.*1.18*sin(\t r)},{0.*1.18*cos(\t r)+1.*1.18*sin(\t r)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives me this image
[image]

How can I color red the thing in middle?

Comment: I'm trying with more coordinates, is there any simple way to get the coordinates?

Comment: Plotting seems an overkill: try with a couple of `arc` actions!

Comment: I'm bad with 'arc' cause I can't find correct angles or this is something like trying until get it?

Comment: I would draw the shape on paper and deconstruct it in few geometric shapes (e.g. four arcs here) and try to manually estimate the coordinates/angles (better if with values that make geometric sense). Another option is drawing the arcs with inkscape and then exporting to tikz.

Comment: @Bordaigorl I've improved the question, thanks

Comment: Is the non-smooth join intended?

Comment: Yes , it is intended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the part in the middle is easier to draw using the `curve to` construction than `.. controls ..`. At least, for me, though I have only recently started to have any clue about the latter so it might just be my lack of experience.

Anyway, this is very close although it is not an absolutely perfect match. (But the faint red line tracing the top of the circle is a viewer artefact, I think, and not an imperfection in construction. But the bit in the middle is not an entirely perfect match.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (-.67,1.06) circle (24.1mm);
  \path [fill=red, even odd rule] (-.67,1.06) coordinate (c1) circle (24.1mm) ++(.01,.65) coordinate (c2) circle (19.2mm);
  \draw [draw=red, fill=red] (c2) +(.05,-19.2mm) [out=25, in=-45] to (-.15,1.95) [out=150, in=-125] to ($(c1) + (.05,24.1mm)$) coordinate (a) [out=-155, in=90] to (-1.45,2.2) [out=-90, in=135] to ++(.51,-1.05) [out=-45, in=70] to cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: thing]

## EDIT

Simply changing the sixth line as suggested in [Luis Felipe's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286335/problem-giving-color-to-a-logo/286392?noredirect=1#comment692032_286392) to

```
  \path [fill=red, even odd rule] (-.67,1.08) coordinate (c1) circle (24.1mm) ++(.01,.65) coordinate (c2) circle (19.2mm);
```

eliminates the faint trace of red line but at the cost of cutting off the tip of the inner part of the logo:

[image: cut off tip]

However, if we set the coordinate used for the inner part before making the adjustment, perhaps we can get the best of both worlds:

```
  \path [fill=red, even odd rule] (-.67,1.06) coordinate (c1) ++(0,0.02) circle (24.1mm) ++(.01,.65) coordinate (c2) circle (19.2mm);
```

[image: best of both?]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (-.67,1.06) circle (24.1mm);
  % tweak based on Luis Felipe's comment: ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286335/problem-giving-color-to-a-logo/286392?noredirect=1#comment692032_286392
  \path [fill=red, even odd rule] (-.67,1.06) coordinate (c1) ++(0,0.02) circle (24.1mm) ++(.01,.65) coordinate (c2) circle (19.2mm);
  \draw [draw=red, fill=red] (c2) +(.05,-19.2mm) [out=25, in=-45] to (-.15,1.95) [out=150, in=-125] to ($(c1) + (.05,24.1mm)$) coordinate (a) [out=-155, in=90] to (-1.45,2.2) [out=-90, in=135] to ++(.51,-1.05) [out=-45, in=70] to cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is solved with 
 
    \path [fill=red, even odd rule] (-.67,1.08) coordinate (c1) circle (24.1mm) ++(.01,.65) coordinate (c2) circle (19.2mm);

in the sixth line

Comment: I don't think that quite works but you're right that it eliminates the trace of red. Please see edit above for a further modification which avoids cutting off the tip of the inner part as well.

Comment: you're right, now is better

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple solution. You may adjust the parameters (`\anglei`, `\angleii`, `\angleiii`, and `\len`) to change the flame.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0,draw=blue]
  \fill[red] (0,0) circle (2.41);
  \begin{scope}[overlay]
    \fill[white] (0,.65) circle (1.92);
  \end{scope}
  \def\anglei{-65}
  \def\angleii{45}
  \def\angleiii{160}
  \def\len{1.5}
  \fill[red]
  (0,.65) ++(0,-1.92)
  arc[start angle=\anglei,end angle=\angleii,radius=\len]
  arc[start angle=\angleii+180,end angle=\angleiii,radius=\len]
  %
  arc[start angle=\anglei+180,end angle=\angleii+180,radius=\len]
  arc[start angle=\angleii+360,end angle=\angleiii+180,radius=\len]
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: setting \len as 1.3 looks nice. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

run with `xelatex`. The origin is the center of the big circle. `\pscustom` builds a closed path which can be filled.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\pscircle*[linecolor=red]{2.41}
\pscircle*[linecolor=white](0,0.65){1.92}
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,linecolor=red]{%
  \psarc(0.65,1.15){1.4}{!2.01 RadtoDeg}{!4.0 RadtoDeg}
  \psarcn(-0.91,-0.79){1.08}{!0.93 RadtoDeg}{!-0.48 RadtoDeg}
  \psarc(-0.58,0){1.43}{!-1.12 RadtoDeg}{!0.68 RadtoDeg}
  \psarcn(1.1,1.94){1.18}{!4.2 RadtoDeg}{!2.72 RadtoDeg}
}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
[...]
```

and run `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex`

Comment: I need to run this in Latex because i'm going to use this image in the header of every page. Is possible run it in latex?

Comment: What do you mean with `latex`? The old program `latex` or `pdflatex`? If you mean `pdflatex` then you can switch to `xelatex` and will have additionally the advantage of using OpenType or TrueType fonts. It is also possible to run `pdflatex` but then you have to load package `auto-pst-pdf`

Comment: I want to run it with pdflatex in a \documentstyle{book} document. What command must I add for doing it? because it works changing pdflatex for xelatex in  compile options but I always work with pdflatex

Comment: see my edited answer. You need only the optional argument `--shell-escape` when running with `pdflatex`.  Which Editor are you using?

Comment: I'm using TexStudio as editor. what to do here? I need open the console for every compilation?

Comment: `Options->Configure TeXstudio->Commands`  and then on the right side insert for `pdflatex`:  `pdflatex -synctex=1 --shell-escape  -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`  Then it will always be used when running `pdflatex`

Comment: this configurations keeps on my machine or in the .tex? because I have to run it in other pc (i'm not the only one who is making this book). It works good

Comment: on the machine, but it doesn't hurt

Comment: @LuisFelipe If you enable shell escape by default, do not compile documents from sources you don't trust. (Although it is no more dangerous than running LuaTeX, as I understand it.) But if you use Arara, you can configure it on a per-document basis within the TeX file itself.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite right, but anyway...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz[line join=round]\filldraw [red] (0,0) 
  arc (270:180-30:cos 45 / cos 30) arc (180-45:360+45:1)
  arc (30:-90:cos 45 / cos 30) -- cycle
  .. controls ++(30:1) and ++(210:3/2) .. (0,1.5)
  .. controls ++(210:1) and ++(30:3/2) .. cycle;
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the middle thing is too hard without a lot of points for control curve